# ggplot2: plotting the data in geom_tile for absence or presence

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to plot a data

```
coords  chr pos ref alt GT  freq    sample
chr1_10126848   chr1    10126848    G   T   0/1 0.1 b1t2
chr1_1022375    chr1    1022375 C   T   0/1 0.018   b1t2
chr1_103025843  chr1    103025843   T   A   0/1 0.125   b1t2
chr1_103025922  chr1    103025922   T   C   0/1 0.314   b1t1
chr1_1042008    chr1    1042008 C   T   0/1 0.031   b1t2
chr1_1051632    chr1    1051632 G   A   0/1 0.03    b1t3
chr1_10599364   chr1    10599364    A   T   0/1 0.208   b1t3
chr1_10599364   chr1    10599364    A   T   0/1 0.308   b1t2
chr1_10599364   chr1    10599364    A   T   0/1 0.108   b1t1
chr1_1062578    chr1    1062578 T   C   0/1 0.207   b1t2
chr1_107480827  chr1    107480827   C   T   0/1 0.14    b1t3
chr1_107480827  chr1    107480827   C   T   0/1 0.54    b1t2
chr1_107480827  chr1    107480827   C   T   0/1 0.24    b1t1
chr1_107480957  chr1    107480957   C   A   0/1 0.214   b1t3
chr1_1084149    chr1    1084149 G   A   0/1 0.036   b1t2
.....
```

using ggplot with as follows:

```
x<-read.table("trial2.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
ggplot(x,aes(sample, coords, fill=freq))+geom_tile()+ theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())+ scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

I am getting following plot: 
[image]
whereas I need something like this:

[image: Desired_output]

could anyone guide as to how should I sort the data so that coords (y-axis) present in all samples should be plotted first and unique to each sample should be plotted last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jason for answering so quick. I also figured it out, although not as sophisticated as yours, but works!

```
x<-read.table("trial.txt", header=T, sep="\t") ## read input file
x1<-merge(x, data.frame(table(coords = x$coords)), by = c("coords")) ## print frequency of each coordinate into new column "Freq". NOTE: "Freq" is different column than "freq"
x2<-arrange(x1, Freq, sample) ## sort the data first by "Freq" and then by "sample"
ggplot(x2,aes(sample, coords))+geom_tile(aes(fill = freq))+ scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") + scale_y_discrete(limits=unique(x2$coords)) + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), plot.title = element_blank(),axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())   ## finally plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create a `total` of the unique number of samples for each `coords` - you could do this with `length(unique(sample))` or more succinctly with `dplyr::n_distinct`. The other concept is that you will want to `reorder` the `coords` by this new variable (in this example, I call this new variable `total`):

```
x %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  group_by(coords) %>%
  mutate(total = n_distinct(sample)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(sample, reorder(coords, total), fill = freq)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]